# How to instantiate custom button from UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to make my button to CustomButton.

```
public class MyCustomButton : UIButton
{
    string customProperty;
}
```

I have already a UIButton. Now I need to make it MyCustomButton.
But explicit type cast results in crash.
How can I instantiate MyCustomButton from already existed UIButton?

Comment: What do you mean by "already existed" button?

Comment: You can't convert one type of object into another with a cast. What do you mean by "from already existed UIButton"? Where did this button come from? If you made it in IB, you can just change your class there to your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more than cast your the button causing the crash, the button needs to actually be an instance of `MyCustomButton`. Wherever it's being created, you need it to be `MyCustomButton` there instead of `UIButton`.